# Chrome.Browser.Extension Errors: Uncaught TypeError and Unchecked runtime.lastError:

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Ok, I am getting two errors with my Extension for chrome, The first error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined
```

with the second error being:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError
```

They both occur in the same javascript file, which is as follows:

```
var contextMenuItem = {
"id": "RemoveItReportItRecordIt",
"title": "Remove It",
"contexts" : ["all"]
};

chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);

chrome.contextMenus.OnClick.addListener(function(clickData) {
    if(clickData.menuItemId == "RemoveItReportItRecordIt")
      {
      if(clickData.SelectionText) return;
      else 
         alert("ClickData = " + clickData);
     }
});
```

Can you tell me and show me what I a doing wrong?

Comment: It's `onClicked`, not `OnClick`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked

Comment: If you're using a proper IDE you can install [@types/chrome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome) to have tooltips and autocomplete for all events and methods in the API.

Comment: @AndrewMyers if you make that an answer you will get the points.

Comment: @DaveGordon Was that the problem? If it was the problem, you should leave the original incorrect name in the question, otherwise an answer pointing out the error wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @AndrewMyers done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct name of the event is [`onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked), not `OnClick`. Using past tense in the event names seems to be fairly common in Chrome's extension API.